# Error: need MAIL command when using smtp with perl

Tags: perl, email, smtp, amazon-ses, smtp-auth

I was trying to send emails using Mime::Lite perl module and through smtp authentication. But unfortunately that doesn't work. It shows

> Error: need MAIL command, Error: command not implemented

Here is the updated code snippet and Debug output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;
use MIME::Base64;


my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new(<mail host>,Port=>587,Debug=>1)or die;
$smtp->starttls();
$smtp->auth($username,$password) or die $!;
my $msg = MIME::Lite -> new ( 
  From  => 'from@mail.com',
  TO    => 'to@mail.com', 
  Subject  => 'Testing Text Message',
  Data     => 'How\'s it going.' );

$smtp->mail(<from mail>);
$smtp->to(<to mail>);
$smtp -> data();
$smtp -> datasend( $msg->as_string() );
$smtp -> dataend(); 
print $smtp ->message();
$smtp -> quit;
```

Debug output:

```
Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(3.10)
Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(3.10)
Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.68)
Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET6(2.71)
Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.36)
Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.34)
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-2108164273 5RjAQr5ZFI284sDt1KWu
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-SIZE 10485760
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-STARTTLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250 Ok
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)>>> STARTTLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 220 Ready to start TLS
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x1e0a920)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-SIZE 10485760
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-STARTTLS
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x1e0a920)<<< 250 Ok
Died at test_script.pl line 17.
```

Please let me know the solution for this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't have any error handling in your code. My guess it that something failed before you issued `$smtp->mail(...)`, i.e. like the authentication failed. Please add debugging to your code (i.e. add `Debug => 1` when calling `Net::SMTP_auth->new`) and include the full debug output into your question.

Comment: 1) Why do you use `Net::SMTP_auth` instead of `Net::SMTP`?  Current version of `Net::SMTP` supports SMTP AUTH. 2) Add `,Debug=>1)` to `Net::SMTP` constructor (new) to get transcript of SMTP session.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for your comments. I have added the debug output to the question, please let me know how to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not have any error checking and that's why you've missed that the authentication failed:

> ```
> Net::SMTP_auth=GLOB(0x13085a8)>>> AUTH LOGIN
> Net::SMTP_auth=GLOB(0x13085a8)<<< 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
> ```

And because the authentication failed it will not accept sending a mail, i.e. `$smtp->mail('admin@testadmin.com');` will result in `Error: need MAIL command, Error: command not implemented`.

Unfortunately, the very very old Net::SMTP_auth (last update 2006) does not have support for STARTTLS. But, current versions of Net::SMTP have support for both auth (so you don't need Net::SMTP_auth) and starttls (starting with Net::SMTP version 3.xx).

With Net::SMTP 3.xx your code should look something like this:

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new( '<emailhost>') or die;
$smtp->starttls or die;
$smtp->auth('<username>', '<password>') or die;
...
```

Comment: we use Net::SMTP version 3.10, Now it does not shows any error but stops at $smtp -> auth( 'LOGIN', '<username>', '<password>') or die;

Comment: @Sayooj: see the updated answer on how you need to use Net::SMTP: first you need to call `starttls` and then you need to call `auth` differently.

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned, by calling `starttls` and then  `auth` differently. But it results same. Could you please share any working code snippet for the same

Comment: @Sayooj: the example code I've given works for me if you replace `<emailhost>` etc with the correct values. Just tested it against `mail.gmx.net:587`. I guess you are missing the SASL module (`Authen::SASL`) since it does not try to authenticate according to the debug output.